# Laravel: How to get last N entries from DB

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have table of dogs in my DB and I want to retrieve **`N latest added dogs`**.

Only way that I found is something like this:

```
Dogs:all()->where(time, <=, another_time);
```

Is there another way how to do it? For example something like this `Dogs:latest(5);`

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: A combination of the `orderBy()` and `limit()` methods; though you do also have `latest()` as an alternative to `orderBy()`

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=16126).

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$dogs = Dogs::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Use `orderBy` with `Descending` order and take the first `n` numbers of records.

**Update (Since the `latest` method has been added):**

```
$dogs = Dogs::latest()->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: What happens if there are only 3 records in this case?

Comment: You'll get three :-)

Comment: This will reverse order of your items. You will have to re-order them in your application. So if you're trying to load last 5 posts sorted by date, don't forget to re-sort them on collection level.

Comment: @TheAlpha I want to fetch from desc but I want to skip the latest 10000 records. Record I want is included in last 20000 but surely not in the latest 10000. Any thoughts?

Comment: @gowlemn, try `Dogs::latest()->skip(10000)->take(10000)->get();
 `.

Answer (score 43):

My solution for cleanliness is:

```
Dogs::latest()->take(5)->get();
```

It's the same as other answers, just with using built-in methods to handle common practices.

Comment: This also works with UUIDs so it's more generic. It doesn't work with tables that don't have timestamps though.

Answer (score 11):

```
Dogs::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a negative integer n to take the last n elements.

```
Dogs::all()->take(-5)
```

This is good because you don't use orderBy which is bad when you have a big table.

Comment: it is not warranted that the last 5 resulted are the last 5 inserted. it USUALLY works, but with no warranty

Comment: I had no success using it. To me -5 and 5 works the same !!!

Answer (score 6):

You may also try like this:

```
$recentPost = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

It's working fine for me in Laravel 5.6

Comment: Yes, method `take` and `limit` is similar. The parent is `limit`, and `take` is just alias. You can check on file Builder.php

Answer (score 2):

[The Alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741747/the-alpha)'s solution is very elegant, however sometimes you need to re-sort (ascending order) the results **in the database** using SQL (to avoid in-memory sorting at the collection level), and an SQL subquery is a good way to achieve this.

It would be nice if Laravel was smart enough to recognise we want to create a subquery if we use the following *ideal* code...

```
$dogs = Dogs::orderByDesc('id')->take(5)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

...but this gets compiled to a single SQL query with conflicting `ORDER BY` clauses instead of the subquery that is required in this situation.

Creating a subquery in Laravel is unfortunately not simply as easy as the following pseudo-code that would be really nice to use...

```
$dogs = DB::subQuery( 
    Dogs::orderByDesc('id')->take(5) 
)->orderBy('id');
```

...but the same result can be achieved using the following code:

```
$dogs = DB::table('id')->select('*')->fromSub(
    Dogs::orderByDesc('id')->take(5)->toBase(), 
    'sq'
)->orderBy('id');
```

This generates the required `SELECT * FROM (...) AS sq ...` sql subquery construct, and the code is *reasonably* clean in terms of readability.)

Take particular note of the use of the `->toBase()` function - which is required because `fromSub()` doesn't like to work with Eloquent model `Eloquent\Builder` instances, but seems to require a `Query\Builder` instance).  (See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35631)

I hope this helps someone else, since I just spent a couple of hours researching how to achieve this myself.  (I had a complex SQL query builder expression that needed to be limited to the last few rows in certain situations).

Answer (score 2):

I use it this way, as I find it cleaner:

```
$covidUpdate = COVIDUpdate::latest()->take(25)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive come up with a solution that helps me achieve the same result using the `array_slice()` method. In my code I did `array_slice( PickupResults::where('playerID', $this->getPlayerID())->get()->toArray(), -5 );` with `-5` I wanted the last 5 results of the query.

Answer (score 1):

For getting last entry from DB

`$variable= Model::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dogs::latest()->take(1)->first();
```

this code return the latest record in the collection

Answer (score 1):

***Can use this `latest()`:***

```
$dogs = Dogs::latest()->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a situation where you want to get the latest record of data from the request header that was just inserted into the database:

```
$noOfFilesUploaded = count( $request->pic );// e.g 4
$model = new Model;

$model->latest()->take($noOfFilesUploaded);
```

This way your `take()` helper function gets the number of array data that was just sent via the request.

You can get only `id`s like so:

`$model->latest()->take($noOfFilesUploaded)->puck('id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
use DB;

$dogs = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) Var1 ORDER BY id ASC"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).