# Laravel last news item by category id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get an overview of the last news items grouped by category id.

Example data:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | title  | category_id |       created_at        |       updated_at        |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Item 1 |           1 | 2020-08-01 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-01 12:00:00.000 |
|  2 | Item 2 |           2 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 |
|  3 | Item 3 |           4 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 |
|  4 | Item 4 |           1 | 2020-08-04 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-04 12:00:00.000 |
|  5 | Item 5 |           2 | 2020-08-11 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-11 12:00:00.000 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

And I want the output:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | title  | category_id |       created_at        |       updated_at        |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  3 | Item 3 |           4 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-02 12:00:00.000 |
|  4 | Item 4 |           1 | 2020-08-04 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-04 12:00:00.000 |
|  5 | Item 5 |           2 | 2020-08-11 12:00:00.000 | 2020-08-11 12:00:00.000 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Is there a easy way to do this with Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: How to get last N entries from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860973/laravel-how-to-get-last-n-entries-from-db)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a self join to news table to pick the latest news for each category like

```
select n.*
from news n
left join news n1 on n.category_id = n1.category_id
and n.created_at < n1.created_at
where n1.category_id is null
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8896a/2)

Using query builder you might rewrite it as

```
DB::table('news as n')
  ->select('n.*')
  ->leftJoin('news as n1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('n.category_id', '=', 'n1.category_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('n.created_at < n1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('n1.category_id')
  ->get();
```