# Take N latest records without using orderBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-optimization

I'm having an optimization problem, where in need to take `n latest` results from database that has a lot of records. I know I can do it by using `orderBy`, but I want to avoid it, because `orderBy` loops through every record, which increases my load & query times. I found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860973/laravel-how-to-get-last-n-entries-from-db) that uses negative number in `take()` which basically takes latest records, but it's not working for me, it takes all the records regardless:

```
Record::all()->take(-5);
```

This is the output of previous code, which only returns empty `Query Builder` instance:

```
  "supplementRecommendationsHistory" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#2485 ▼
    #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#2484 ▶}
    #model: App\RecommendedSupplement {#2483 ▶}
    #eagerLoad: array:2 [▶]
    #localMacros: []
    #onDelete: null
    #passthru: array:17 [▶]
    #scopes: []
    #removedScopes: []
  }
```

Is there a different aproach to this? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Simply `latest` indicates that you want ordering to be made. If you have auto-increment column, then find next ID from table schema and do `WHERE id > :{nextIndex - N}`

Comment: @Justinas is exactly right. Think of your table as an unordered set of rows. You necessarily must use `orderBy` unless you want your results in an unpredictable order. The good news? when you `orderBy` an indexed column in your table it's not nearly as expensive as you assume.

Comment: See this article about group by / limit optimization in mysql
https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. I went with @Justinas suggestion ```WHERE id > :{nextIndex - N}``` and it seems to work for now.

Comment: @zlatan Can you post implementation as answer? Because obviously `WHERE id > :{nextIndex - N}` as plain query will never work

Comment: Will do, give me a few minutes @Justinas

Comment: What kind of database are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQLServer?

Comment: Show us the generated SQL and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I added my solution down below, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestion from the comments (@Justinas), this is how I implemented `WHERE id > :{nextIndex - N}` solution:

```
RecommendedTest::where('id', '>', RecommendedTest::max('id') - 20)->get()->reverse()->values();
```

This way I could get latest 20 records from a huge database. I also used `reverse()->values()` to revert ordering of the results, which basically gave me results sorted by created_at column, which was my initial goal. The query didn't take long, around ~1000ms, which was okay for me, as this was temporary solution.

Documentation for the [reverse](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reverse) and [values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values) methods